# Python 3.4 code not giving any errors nor results

Tags: python

I typed the below code to invoke the Calculate button of my calculator, however it does not give me any results when i run it. it does not give me errors eithe. Can you please help me with what I am doing wrong as this is my very first Gui app.I am very new to programming.

```
from __future__ import division    
import sys
from SalesTax import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget. __init__(self,parent)
        self.ui =Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.calculateButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.calculate)

    def calculate(self):
        if len(self.ui.linePrice.text())!=0:
            price= int(self.ui.linePrice.text())
        else:
            price=0

        if len(self.ui.SpinTaxRate.text())!=0:
            taxRate= int(self.ui.spinTaxRate.value())
        else:
            taxRate =0

        tax = price*(taxRate/100)
        self.ui.lineResult.setText("Sales Tax on the product is:" +str(tax))

if __name__ =="__main __":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: maybe better post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Why are you invoking `sys.exit` ?

Comment: @omri_saadon the [examples on pyqt](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/widgets/calculator.py) have this pattern

Comment: @omri, the examples always say we invoke sys.exit at the end. thank you

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/widgets/calculator.py) the `MyForm` class should inherit from `QWidget`, not `QWindow`:

```
class Calculator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Calculator, self).__init__(parent)
```

You're also using `QtGui.QWidget. __init__(self,parent)` in your `__init__`.

Comment: thank you for your response . MyForm is inheriting from QMainWindow because that is the template that I used when designing the interface and not Widgets

Comment: Then you should use the proper call in your class' `__init__`. You can also use the `super` call rather than the explicit constructor.